# Check which community a node belongs in louvain community detection

Tags: r, igraph

So I have run louvain detection on my dataset and returns a bunch of communities with nodes included. My question is, given a node, how do you find which community it belongs to? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The community for each node is stored in the `membership` component of the result.

```
library(igraph)
set.seed(1234)
G = erdos.renyi.game(16, 0.22)
C = cluster_louvain(G)
plot(G, vertex.color=rainbow(3,alpha=0.4)[C$membership])
```

[image: Clustered graph]