# R: identifying points in a graph (possible with dplyr?)

Tags: r, graph, dplyr, data-visualization, nodes

I found a previous stackoverflow post that deals with a similar question that I have, but the answer there is not quite the same : [Check which community a node belongs in louvain community detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52245816/check-which-community-a-node-belongs-in-louvain-community-detection)

I created some data in R and then made a graph. After making the graph, I performed clustering on the graph. Now, suppose I have a list of people, I want to find out which cluster they belong to.

I understand that it is easy to manually inspect the data and find this out, however I think this would be very difficult to do if you had a big data set.

I have written the code below. Everything works until the last 2 lines where I try to find out which clusters do "John", "Peter" and "Tim" belong to:

```
#load libraries
        library(igraph) 
    library(dplyr)
    

#create data
        Data_I_Have <- data.frame(
               
                "Node_A" = c("John", "John", "John", "Peter", "Peter", "Peter", "Tim", "Kevin", "Adam", "Adam", "Xavier"),
                "Node_B" = c("Claude", "Peter", "Tim", "Tim", "Claude", "Henry", "Kevin", "Claude", "Tim", "Henry", "Claude")
                
            )

#create graph
               
                graph <- graph.data.frame( Data_I_Have, directed=F)
                graph <- simplify(graph)
    
#perform clustering
        cluster = cluster_louvain(graph)

#plot graph
            plot(graph, cluster)

#make list of people
people <- c("John", "Peter", "Tim")

#find out which cluster each of these people belong in (here is the error)
location <- names("people")[!(names("people") %in% cluster)]

#transform the previous data frame into a table
location_table <- table(location)
```

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: I think you mean `graph <- graph.data.frame(Data_I_Have, directed=F)` and `plot(cluster, graph)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The membership of the vertices are held in `$membership` and the names of the vertices are in `$names`:

```
cluster$membership[match(people,cluster$names)]
#[1] 2 3 1
```

Or if you prefer, you can use the accessor function `igraph::membership`:

```
membership(cluster)[people]
# John Peter   Tim 
#    2     3     1
```

See `help(communities)` for more information.

Example data:

```
cluster <- structure(list(membership = c(2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3), memberships = structure(c(2, 
3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3), .Dim = c(1L, 8L)), modularity = 0.115702479338843, 
    names = c("John", "Peter", "Tim", "Kevin", "Adam", "Xavier", 
    "Claude", "Henry"), vcount = 8L, algorithm = "multi level"), class = "communities")
```

Comment: Nice. I've used these functions a bunch of times, but always get confused as to what help file relates to what in *igraph*. This is really helpful.

Comment: @Ian : thank you! this is exactly what I was looking for! (and I fixed the typo, thank you!)

Comment: Here is how you make this into a table :  a = membership(cluster)[people]


 b = data.frame(a)


b$names <- rownames(b)

Comment: sort: s = b[order(b$a, decreasing = TRUE),]